# Appending data from files listed in a file

Tags: performance, vba, excel, database

I am working on a project that requires me to write VBA code which, upon a button press, loads the data from certain files in a given directory.
In my testing, I was able to load the data from 1100 files in about 5 minutes which is not bad. I would, however, like it to be faster if possible. I am very new to VBA so I don't if much can be done to optimize this code.

The code (see below) works as follows:

1. The Load Data button is pressed in the worksheet
2. The code looks in the directory which is specified in a certain cell (or hardcoded)
3. It searches for the files with "VBT_" in their name and loads the data from the file
   into the sheet. Here I have some spacing loops running (see comments and the variable
   "i") to make sure the data is placed correctly.
4. Each suitable file is opened and if it is more recent (time of last change) than the
   last updating of the data sheet, the data from it is appended to the sheet. To do
   this each file is opened and closed.
5. Once all suitable files have been checked and data from the recent ones added to the
   list the time of the last update is updated and the sub ends.

Please note that you will have to provide your own file path to a directory with suitable files if you want to test this out. My files have 16 (columns A-N) rows with data and I insert an extra row for spacing.

I am aware of a method using ActiveX pipelines that allows the data to be loaded in without opening the files. I have not tested it yet because it didn't seem worth the effort. However, if you have experience using it, please share your thoughts on its performance. Do you think it would offer a significant improvement?

The code:

```
'Loads data from the given repository. Works by appending only the most recent data to the already loaded data without changing it
Private Sub LoadData_Click()

'Hopeful optimization
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim wB As Workbook
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim wsTB As Worksheet
Dim SrcRg As Range 'Search range
Dim filename As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim newtimestamp As Date
Dim oldtimestamp As Date
Dim nulldate As Date
Dim new_oldtimestamp As Date
Dim finalnew_oldtimestamp As Date

i = 4
Set wsTB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Find the first empty row and start copying
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    i = i + 17
Loop

'Using the VBT tag we make sure that the correct files are selected
'*VBT* is needed, just \VBT_* does not work

'We store the path to the current data repository in this cell. This way it can be easily changed.
filepath = Cells(2, 6).Value
filename = Dir(filepath & "*VBT_*")

'The time of the last data update is stored here
oldtimestamp = Cells(1, 6).Value
finalnew_oldtimestamp = oldtimestamp

'We keep track of the time a file has been updated so that we can set the last data update accordingly
'The last data update needs to match the latest time at which a file from the batch that was loaded in was updated at
new_oldtimestamp = FileDateTime(filepath & filename)
nulldate = "00:00:00"

    'Checks if we have a file selected
    Do While Len(filename) <> 0
        newtimestamp = FileDateTime(filepath & filename)
        
        'Checks is the selected file is older than the files from the last data update
        If (newtimestamp > oldtimestamp) Or (oldtimestamp = nulldate) Then
            
            'load data
            Set wB = Workbooks.Open(filepath & filename, True)
            Set wS = wB.Sheets(1)
            Set SrcRg = wS.Range("A1:N17")
            wsTB.Range("A" & i).Resize(SrcRg.Rows.Count, SrcRg.Columns.Count).Value = SrcRg.Value
            wB.Close
            Rows(i + 16).Interior.Color = RGB(165, 210, 255) 'Color a separating row for easier reading
                 
            'Set new timestamp
            If newtimestamp > new_oldtimestamp Then
                new_oldtimestamp = newtimestamp
                finalnew_oldtimestamp = new_oldtimestamp
            End If
             
            'After data transfer jump far enough to write the data from the next table
            i = i + 17
        End If
        
        'Pick the next file
        filename = Dir
    Loop
'If new files have been found this will update the timestamp for correct lookup thenext time the macro is used
oldtimestamp = finalnew_oldtimestamp

'The time the last update is written in this cell
Cells(1, 6).Value = oldtimestamp

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```